# How is a tranquilizer gun used?

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, weapons

A tranquilizer gun doesn't give any health damage, but I'm assuming once damage given equals to size the victim falls unconscious (stun rule).

- Is the damage dealt proportional to the tranquilizer dose?
- Does the attacker needs to hit the target with multiple darts to render them unconscious? Or in other words, does the damage equal to size need to be delivered in one hit, or can a tranq gun's stun damage accumulate over multiple hits?

Comment: While cleaning up the question, I noticed that the last point had nothing to do with how tranquiliser guns are used, and we have a "one subject per question" rule, so I removed it: *"What happens when a vampire feeds on a victim stunned with tranquilizer?"* You're welcome to post it as a new question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hunter: the Vigil p248

> Dart gun: used primarily for animal control and zoological
>    research. Does no damage but delivers a dose of tranquilizer upon
>    a successful hit. Modifying a dart to contain a different substance
>   requires a successful Dexterity + Crafts roll with a -2 penalty;
>    failure results in destruction of the dart and loss of its intended
>    contents. A character or creature hit with a tranquilizer dart
>    must succeed on a Stamina + Resolve roll to stay conscious,
>    with a bonus of (Size -3) to the roll and a -1 penalty per each
>    additional dart. Unconsciousness lasts for 10 minutes per dart.

and a much less useful entry in Armory p91 (referenced pages from this quote are for knockout gas not dart delivery methods)

> Dart Gun: Dart guns use compressed air to fire tranquilizer
>   or radio tracking darts. All dart guns are quiet weapons and have
>   the effective benefits of suppressors (see p. 167). A successful dart
>   gun attack does no significant damage (unless the target is Size
>   2 or smaller, in which case a dart gun inflicts one Health level
>   of lethal damage). Instead, a dart gun delivers the dart’s payload
>   into the target’s bloodstream. Darts are commercially available
>   with tranquilizer solution only. See p. 127 for information on
>   knockout drugs and other poisons. A tracking dart has a 12-hour
>   battery life and appropriate RDF (radio direction-finding; Size
>   4, Cost •••) gear can detect it up to 20 miles away.

as an aside comment, given the origins of this question, I would suggest that these do not work on Vampires. Vampires blood does not need to circulate, thus there is no real delivery method.